# Ajax html via POST method to mail function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page with various elements on. I use some jquery to get all the elements with a checked select box, send them via Ajax to a mail function (_POST). However, when I get the HTML through to my Inbox, all else seems fine apart from a load of backslashes in my HTML. But only the HTML that cam from the tables. The message HTML such as the head and doctype are all fine. Im guessing I need to encode and decode my POST in someway.

```
           jQuery('#search-query-send').click(function() {

              var content = '';               
              var email = jQuery('#email').val();

              jQuery('.selectthis input:checked').each(function() {
                content += jQuery(this).parents('div.apartment-entry-container').html();
              });



              jQuery.ajax({
                url: "http://www.greenmonkeypublicrelations.com/scpads/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'action=apartmentsearchemail&email=' + email + '&content=' + content,
                success: function(result) {
                  //got it back, now assign it to its fields.                     
                  alert('Your message has been sent.');
                  console.log(result);
                }
              });
            });
```

A line of code from my inbox.

```
<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\" class=\"bookings-aligntop container-table apartment-entry\">
```

Comment: issue with in admin-ajax.php in stripslashes($_POST['content']);

Comment: you mean the posted string has extra unwanted slashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add stripslashes($mail_body) on ajax.php file

```
$msg =
"<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<body bgcolor='#FFD75B'><br /><br />
<table cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' border='0' align='center' bgcolor='#ffffff'>
<tr>
    <td align='center'><img src='http://www.BSFlag.com/images/BS-flagGIF.gif' width='301' height='141' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='center' width='600'><h1>" . $FromEmail . " has sent you the BS Flag</h1>
    <h2>for the following reasons:</h2>
<blockquote>" . $Reason . "</blockquote>
<p><em>Learn more about the BS Flag at <a href='http://www.bsflag.com'>www.bsflag.com</a>.</em></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
</body>
</html>";


//send mail
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n";
$headers .= "From: "".$companyName."" <".$companyEmail.">\n";    

mail("$to", stripslashes($subject), stripslashes($msg), $headers) or die("Could not send e-mail - Error A46GY7");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

```
 var html = $.parseHTML(content);

jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://www.greenmonkeypublicrelations.com/scpads/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'action=apartmentsearchemail&email=' + email + '&content=' + html,
            success: function(result) {
              //got it back, now assign it to its fields.                     
              alert('Your message has been sent.');
              console.log(result);
            }
          });
```

Make sure its handled in the PHP side

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <yourfromemail@atyourcompany.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```